# why textAlign:'center' not working in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

how to make lable horizontally center .I used  textAlign:'center'.But it is not working .here is my code
https://rnplay.org/apps/ZN2gvA

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react-native';
const {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  Text,
  View

}=React;

const styles=React.StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    paddingTop:20,
     textAlign:'center',

  },
  label:{
   color:'blue',
   backgroundColor:'red'   

}
})

class SampleApp extends Component{
  render(){

    return (<View style={styles.container}><Text style={styles.label}>hello</Text></View>)
  }

}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pay a little more attention to the warnings that React Native is giving you:

[image]

The style `textAlign: 'center'` works only for `Text` components. Please look at the styles documentation for [`View`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#style) and [`Text`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#style).

In your case remove `textAlign: 'centre'` from `container` and add it to `label`. Check out the changes I made at https://rnplay.org/apps/RQX5Fw